# c# Impersonate user after forms authentification

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, impersonation, form-authentication

Untill today, I used windowd authentification for my society intranet (built in asp mvc 3.0). However, because an urgent need to log of users, I had to pass to forms authentification.

All it's good now, except one function that I used for explore a directory in the server. Depending of the of user rights, the user could read some directories and files. This is my function:

```
public static MvcHtmlString Explore()
    {
        WindowsIdentity id = (WindowsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;

        MvcHtmlString s = null;
        using (System.Security.Principal.WindowsImpersonationContext context = System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(id.Token))
        {
            try
            {
                s = new MvcHtmlString(Explore(documentsRootFolder).ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(e.Message+"<br/>");
                HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(e.StackTrace);
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    private static StringBuilder Explore(string path)
    {

        StringBuilder writer = new StringBuilder();
        writer.Append("<ul>");
        try
        {
            foreach (var a in System.IO.Directory.GetDirectories(path))
            {
                writer.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", a.Replace((path.EndsWith(@"\") ? path : path+@"\"), string.Empty));
                writer.Append(Explore(a));

            }

            foreach (var a in System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(path))
            {
                string url = a.Replace(documentsRootFolder, string.Empty).Replace(@"\", "/");
                string friendlyName = a.Replace((path.EndsWith(@"\") ? path : path + @"\"), string.Empty);
                writer.AppendFormat("<li><a href=\"Open?path={0}\">{1}</a></li>", url, friendlyName);
            }
        }
        catch { }
        writer.Append("</ul>");
        return writer;
    }
```

**Of course, with forms authentification, i can't get windows identity from HttpContext user. How I can read directories and files now?**

P.S: I tried to use the advapi32.dll to get windows identity of the user. However, after the logon, it's impossible to logout without closing the browser (ssi). That is why I search another solution. Is it possible to get windows identity token whithout logon?

Thanks

Comment: If you need to log users off automatically due to security concerns in an intranet application, have you thought about asking your IT administrators to force Windows sessions to lock automatically instead, since it will probably achieve the same objective.

Comment: no, I want to allow users to log of when they want too (for exemple, to log in with another user account...)

Answer (score 1):

Probably not safe, nor recommended. But you could persist the username and password in a Session var or something. Then use Impersonation when needed via [this class](https://gist.github.com/mxmissile/8f2ef5ed3f5687e9053f).

```
using(new Impersonation("username","domain","password"))
{
  s = new MvcHtmlString(Explore(documentsRootFolder).ToString());
}
```

Comment: Persisting the user's credentials in a Session var, is probably questionable.

Comment: If i store in the session the Impersantion object and dispose it when user log out, is this more safe?

Comment: No, dont do that. Only use the Impersonation class when you actually need to impersonate.